# What should we do with questions which are looking like sample code but are a proof of concept implementation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Yesterday I stumbled over 2 questions which seemed to be sample code.

[The first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80234/29371) stated

> I wrote a sample project to show you my model. What do you think about it?

and [the other](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80208/29371) had code like

```
public async Task TheMethod(int id, string val)
```

and

```
// DO LONG RUNNING TASK
await Task.Delay(3000);
Console.WriteLine(id + " " + val + " at time " + DateTime.Now.ToString("m:ss"));
```

Usually I would vote to close both of the questions.

For the first one I would have voted but I hadn't been entirely sure also because I already commented on the op's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436427/java-mvc-model-for-large-scale-gui-using-annotations) on Stack Overflow.

I did vote to close the second one and it is on hold right now (also it seems to be running code but just **looks like** sample code).

Should we add a tag [proof-of-concept](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-of-concept) or should we decide from case to case if a question like these are on/off topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speaking in general, without passing judgement on the two cited questions…

I'd say that a [proof-of-concept] tag wouldn't work well.  Tagging is too black-and-white an act for such a nuanced decision.  Furthermore, the distinction between proof-of-concept and hypothetical code is so thin, if it exists at all, that I would have a hard time explaining it.

Users who think that the question is off-topic should, of course, vote to close.  I wish there were a counterbalancing vote to not-close feature available, but there isn't.  I think that the next best thing would be to write a comment in defense of keeping the question open, and hope that others agree not to close it.

Comment: sounds fair to me

Comment: The only way to vote to not-close is to vote "Leave open" in the Close review queue.

Comment: Everyone who has viewed the question and not voted to close has voted to not-close...

Answer (score 4):

I have reopened [Code snippet for a method dealing with IDs from multiple threads](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80208/9357).  I agree with @Heslacher's observation that, despite the fact that the code is packaged in a function called `TheMethod()`, and the presence of a `await Task.Delay(3000); // DO LONG RUNNING TASK` placeholder, this code solves a concrete problem, and is far from a general / hypothetical best-practices question.

I'd like to point out that the author of the code is probably having difficulty putting a name on the problem that the code solves.  Suggestions for naming is one of the topics that could be covered in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

With [Java MVC model for large scale GUI using annotations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80234/9357), I initially closed it, then reopened it at @Vogel612's request.

On closer examination, I agreed with @Vogel612's reasoning.  The question about annotation support is centered around the `View.ButtonAction.actionPerformed()` method.  Most of the other code was just supporting material to demonstrate how to take advantage of that annotation mechanism.

For a while, I was going to ask the author to revise the question to better distinguish the core from the example code, but considering that it was a new user who had already made a decent effort to ask a good question, and that @Vogel612 had already posted an answer, I decided that being so fussy wasn't worth it.